# List of files existing in branchA and branchB

Tags: git

Suppose we need to get list of files existing in `branchA` and `branchB`.

Trivial solution is to get two separate list of files for each branch and then intersect them with `bash` or something:

```
# pseudocode
let α = git ls-tree -r --name-only branchA
let β = git ls-tree -r --name-only branchB
intersect α β
```

It seems to be that `ls-tree` command is not an exclusive approach here. Is there a way to do get an answer via git only?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this (assuming a `bash` shell):

```
comm -12 <(git ls-tree -r --name-only branchA | sort) <(git ls-tree -r --name-only branchB | sort)
```

If you don't have `bash`, or your `bash` happens to be old enough not to support that form of process substutution, you can save the output to temporary files:

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only branchA | sort > /tmp/file1
git ls-tree -r --name-only branchB | sort > /tmp/file2
comm -12 /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2
rm /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2
```

I don't think you can get what you want using `git` alone, as any form of `git diff` would look at the *content* of the files as well as the names, and it appears you're wanting just a list of common names, regardless of whether the content is the same or not..